# pandas.DataFrame.round outputs different numbers of decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Calling `round(2)` on the following DataFrame results in one column with 2 decimal places, as expected, but the other column has only 1 decimal place.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0.829, 0.801],
    [0.997, 0.997]
])

df.round(2)
```

When this is run in a notebook, it outputs:

```
      0    1
0  0.83  0.8
1  1.00  1.0
```

I think this is because `0.801` rounds to `0.8`, so only one decimal place is needed, and the other row goes to `1.0` instead of `1.00`.

But I want to output this DataFrame to a LaTeX table, so I'd prefer the same number of decimal places in both columns. Is there a way to force pandas to output 2 decimal places for all columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try string formatting,

```
df.round(2).applymap('{:.2f}'.format)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda expressions to map string formatting onto the columns:

```
df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: f"{x:.2f}")
```